# Should one make a question on-topic by editing it and generalizing it?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, scope, reopen-request

I recently came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626096/steam-package-conflict) in the `Reopen votes` review queue, and it was edited and generalized by another user:

[image]

But as ElementaryOS is not Ubuntu should this really be reopened now that it is generalized? I mean if we get a Red Hat question should we simply edit out the OS and generalize it rather than closing it as off-topic, or is ElementaryOS similar enough to Ubuntu for this question to be generalized here and then reopened?

Comment: Elementary is based on Ubuntu, while RedHat is a completely different Linux distribution. It is not even based on Debian. The similarities of Ubuntu and ElementaryOS are IMHO big eough to generalize this question, except if it's clear that the problem is specific to one of the differences between the two OS.

Comment: I rolled back that edit. This is question hijacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No!

#### If it's off-topic, it's off topic...

Use these comments instead:

**Mint:**

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
```

**Apple:**

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Apple stuff is off-topic here as well.** However, on [apple.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all fruity varieties, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
```

**Android:**

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Android is off-topic here as well.** However, on [Android.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all things Android, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
```

**Kali:**

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Kali is off-topic here as well.** However, on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, especially if you use the *Kali-Linux* tag.  **;-)**
```

**elementary:**<sub>Yup, that's the correct spelling: not "Elementary OS"</sub>

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so elementary is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at elementary, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
```

**Windows:**

```
We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the **people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows**, but not very good at getting it to work when it has problems...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
```

Comment: I liked the dual-boot reference in the Windows comment and was wondering why the Apple comment doesn't mention dual booting OS X and Ubuntu.

Comment: @tepples: because I've never seen any question ever about replacing OSX with Ubuntu...  **:P  ;-)**